# declare variable in custom control structure in scala

Tags: scala

I am wondering if there is a way to create a temp variable in the parameter list of a  custom control structure.

Essentially, I would like create a control structure that looks something like the 
for loop where I can create a variable, i, and have access to i in the loop body only:

```
for(i<- 1 to 100) {
   //loop body can access i here
}
//i is not visible outside
```

I would like to do something similar in my code. For example,

```
customControl ( myVar <- "Task1") {
    computation(myVar)
}

customControl ( myVar <- "Task2") {
    computation(myVar)
}
def customControl (taskId:String) (  body: => Any) = {
    Futures.future {
        val result = body

        result match {
            case Some(x) =>
                logger.info("Executed successfully")
                x
            case _ =>
                logger.error(taskId + " failed")
                None
        }

    }
}
```

Right now, I get around the problem by declaring a variable outside of the custom control structure, which doesn't look very elegant.

```
val myVar = "Task1"
customControl {
    computation(myVar)
}

val myVar2 = "Task2"    
customControl {
    computation(myVar2 )
}
```

Comment: It should be possible to write a macro to do this using untyped macros. I don't have time to write it now, but the basic idea would be to have a macro with two parameter lists which would rewrite into a single block placing the binding at the start of the second block. I started doing something simple called [scala-where](https://github.com/nc6/scala-where) which might give you an idea of where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import scala.actors.Futures

def custom(t: String)(f: String => Any) = {
  Futures.future {
    val result = f(t)

    result match {
      case Some(x) =>
        println("Executed successfully")
        x
      case _ =>
        println(t + " failed")
        None
    }

  }
}
```

And then you can get syntax like this, which isn't exactly what you asked for, but spares you declaring the variable on a separate line:

```
scala> custom("ss") { myvar => println("in custom " + myvar); myvar + "x" }
res7: scala.actors.Future[Any] = <function0>
in custom ss
ss failed

scala> custom("ss") { myvar => println("in custom " + myvar); Some(myvar + "x") }
in custom ss
Executed successfully
res8: scala.actors.Future[Any] = <function0>

scala>
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that the built-in `for (x <- expr) body` is just syntactic sugar for

```
expr foreach (x => body)
```

Thus it might be possible to achieve what you want (using the existing `for` syntax) by defining a custom `foreach` method.

Also note that there is already a `foreach` method that applies to strings. You could do something like this:

```
case class T(t: String) {
  def foreach(f: String => Unit): Unit = f(t)
}
```

*Note*: You can also change the result type of `f` above from `Unit` to `Any` and it will still work.

Which would enable you to do something like

```
for (x <- T("test"))
  print(x)
```

This is just a trivial (and useless) example, since now `for (x <- T(y)) f(x)` just *abbreviates* (or rather "enlongishes") `f(y)`. But of course by changing the argument of `f` in the above definition of `foreach` from `String` to something else and doing a corresponding translation from the string `t` to this type, you could achieve more useful effects.